# Oracle Apex 5: Procedure not working for counter?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm trying to create a page counter. everytime someone enters a page a procedure is executed. 1 is added to the column `check_count`. Unfortunately Oracle Apex 5 is saying

> ORA-24344: success with compilation error.

Why do you think that is?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_counter(person IN varchar2) IS
count pageTable.check_count%type;
countTwo pageTable.check_count%type;
BEGIN
SELECT check_count INTO count FROM pageTable
 WHERE person = pageTable.person_name;
 countTwo := count + 1;
 INSERT INTO  pageTable (check_count)
 VALUES(countTwo);
END;
```

Comment: Any help would be really really appreciated. I'm still trying and researching and trying again and again to solve it.

Comment: WoW. I fixed it! Haha. I'm so happy. It may be that count is a protected term. Also that I was selecting into count a value where count was NULL. Instead before the select i made count := 0; but instead of count I called it alpha. alpha := 0;